# AsyncTask task is not working if internet in unable

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to execute an AsyncTask but it is not running if internet in disable. As soon as i turn on the internet, AsyncTask call

```
LocalGroupUser localGroupUser = new LocalGroupUser(this);
    localGroupUser.execute(group.getGroupID());
```

**AsyncTask**

```
   /**
 * Created by mindit on 3/15/2016.
 */
public class LocalGroupUser extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Activity activity;

    public LocalGroupUser(Activity context)
    {
        this.activity = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String groupId = params[0];
        GroupDB groupDB = new GroupDB(this.activity);
      GlobalData.users = groupDB.getgroupUser(groupId);
        return String.valueOf(true);
    }

    public void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        if(GlobalData.users!=null) {
            ((main_ui) this.activity).showUsersFromLocal();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: are you doing any network call in groupDB.getgroupUser(groupId) ?

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't happen automatically. Add the code for where you use the async task

Comment: No @Thilek We are not doing any network call, We are just getting some data from local DB

Comment: @VishvaNathSingh this is weird then. Since you are just doing db calls, why not use loaders ?

Comment: `We are just getting some data from local DB` by local you mean on mobile or local LAN ??

Comment: @Yazan By mobile  local DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsyncTasks don't run on separate threads-  they all run on one thread in the order they're executed (by default).  So if you have

```
taskWithNetworkNeeded.execute();
taskWithoutNetwork.execute();
```

Then taskWithoutNetwork will not run until taskWithNetworkNeeded finishes.  Which obviously requires the internet.

To get around this, don't use execute.  Use  `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)`  This will force the async task to get its own thread (use this on the without network one at a minimum).

Answer (score 0):

Pal! You can this code as I am assuming that you are getting any data over the network!
if the method return true you can call the async task otherwise show a Toast.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
        this._context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null)
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null)
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: No @Thilek We are not doing any network call, We are just getting some data from local DB

Answer (score 0):

Please include the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in your manifest file.
```

before calling the async task please check the condition for internet connectivity

Comment: No @Thilek We are not doing any network call, We are just getting some data from local DB